# vertically centering a floating image

Tags: html, css

I have a few buttons in my ui that have to have images floating next to the text and this is working well. However, I'm having issues vertically aligning that image to the text.

I've tried multiple things along with `vertical-align: center;`, trying to use absolute positioning, and I even tried some transform technique that failed spectacularly.

Now the content for these buttons is coming from users so it is dynamic, otherwise I would try to do something with line height and call it a day.

Any help would be amazing!

My html looks something like this.

```
<div class='btn-primary col-md-4'>
    <img  src='https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/imgs/placeholder--small.png'/ >
        <span class='imgInfo'>This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. This is info. </span>
        <p class='clearfix'></p>
</div>
```

and the css looks something like this.

```
img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.imgInfo{
    margin-left: 0px;
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    padding-left:1em
}
```

and a jsFiddle to plat with http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7356/

Comment: Is the size of the image always the same?

Comment: @Rob No, it can be anything. The user has the ability to switch out the image and the text.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/52VtD/7358/)**

css

```
img{
    float:left;
    width:50%;;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

(ref: [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/))

#### Explanation

After researching specs and documentation, this is how Absolute Centering works:

1. In the [normal content flow](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#Layout)15, `margin: auto;` equals ’0′ for the top and bottom.
       [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#normal-block)16: If ‘margin-top’, or ‘margin-bottom’ are ‘auto’, their used value is 0.
2. `position: absolute;` breaks the block out of the typical content flow, rendering the rest of the content as if that block weren’t there.
       [Developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)17: …an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space
3. Setting `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;` gives the browser a new bounding box for the block. At this point the block will fill all available space in its offset parent, which is the body or `position: relative;` container. [Developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Notes)1918: For absolutely positioned elements, the top, right, bottom, and left properties specify offsets from the edge of the element’s containing block (what the element is positioned relative to).
4. Giving the block a `width` or a `height` prevents the block from taking up all available space and forces the browser to calculate `margin: auto` based on the new bounding box. [Developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Notes)1918: The margin of the [absolutely positioned] element is then positioned inside these offsets.
5. Since the block is absolutely positioned and therefore out of the normal flow, the browser gives equal values to `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` centering the element in the bounds set earlier.
         [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height)20: If none of the three [top, bottom, height] are ‘auto’: If both ‘margin-top’ and ‘margin-bottom’ are ‘auto’, solve the equation under the extra constraint that the two margins get equal values. AKA: center the block vertically

Absolute Centering appears to be the intended use for `margin: auto;` based on the spec and should therefore work in every standards compliant browser.

**TL;DR:** Absolutely positioned elements aren’t rendered in the normal flow, so `margin: auto;` centers vertically within the bounds set by `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use -

```
img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 5px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` will prevent each other to touch the edge.

And `margin: auto;` will correctly align the `img` to center.

Working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/52VtD/7362/)

Comment: This is unfortunately not responsive. The image overlaps the text if the screen becomes too small.

Comment: Then you could use `width: calc(50% - 20px);` Because I was using `20px` as a left value. Updated my answer also.

Comment: Is the calc cross browser? I have to go all the way back to ie8 and all other browsers.

Comment: calc() isn't supported by IE8. You might use 45% of width for the `img` then. So, the `img` will not overlap the texts.

Comment: I kind of need the image to be the same size as the text though. Otherwise it becomes very tiny. There is no telling what the user might upload so it has to be half and half. :/ That is what my requirements team is telling me.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it. Used `width: 50%` for both images and texts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58719/discussion-between-aniskhan001-and-zazvorniki).

Comment: I think I'm actually going to have to give up on aligning it altogether. My QA team is breathing down my neck and I can't spend any more time on this. Too many issues came out of positioning it to fix, like the image coming out of the container if too large. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use

```
.img {
  margin-top:40%
}
```

instead of vertical-align.

Comment: What about when the info grows? The content is dynamic and I have no idea what they may put in it weather it's large or small.